# Should the Date and Time be stored in the same DateTime field or in different Dates and Times?

Tags: excel, powerquery

The goal: to connect a **CSV** file to **Excel** and analyze it.
Example of an analysis of **DateTime**:

1. Groupings;
2. Sorting;
3. Filters;
4. Charting;
5. DateTime calculations. (presumably)

---

**1.** **Datetime** store
- **Var-1**. in one field: **DateTime**
or
- **Var-2**. in different fields: **Date**, **Time**, **Milliseconds**, **time zone**?
Or use **Var-1** and **Var-2** depending on the circumstances and both options are allowed?

So that you can connect **CSV** to **Excel** without additional settings?
Or with minimal settings: for example, change the format of the table field in **Excel**.
Well, or in **PowerQuery** to "tweak" something in small things.

I.e. so that the data goes the way of **CSV** -> **PowerQuery** -> **Excel**.
Under the maximum **DateTime** i understand: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.MS +zone

**Example:** `2024-03-19 13:18:31.395 +03:00`

---

**2.**
For example, I made several columns with different representation options **DateTime**.
I have considered several column options:

- **Column1:** 2024-03-21 15:24:36,897 +03:00 - Date time,Milliseconds +zone;
- **Column2:** 2024-03-21 15:24:36,897 - milliseconds are separated by ",";
- **Column3:** 2024-03-21 15:24:36.897 - milliseconds are separated by ".";
- **Column4:** 2024-03-21 15:24:36 - Datetime;
- **Column5:** 2024-03-21 - Date;
- **Column6:** 15:24:36 - Time;
- **Column7:** 897 - milliseconds;
- **Column8:** +03:00 - zone.

**3.** My concerns.
**3.1** If you use **Column1**(or **Column2**).
**PowerQuery** recognized the field type as **Text**.
I am afraid that if I build a pivot table or use a table obtained from a query in other tables, the data will not be recognized as **datetime**

**3.2** If you use **Column3**.
Milliseconds and time zone are not displayed in **Column3**
Then **Column3** should be used together with the fields **Column7**(milliseconds), **Column8**(time zone).

**csv**

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 | Column6 | Column7 | Column8 | Column9 | Column10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-03-21 15:24:36,897 +03:00 | 2024-03-21 15:24:36,897 | 21.03.2024 15:24 | 21.03.2024 15:24 | 21.03.2024 | 15:24:36 | 897 | +03:00 | INF | Messaeg-i - 0 |
| 2024-03-21 15:24:38,192 +03:00 | 2024-03-21 15:24:38,192 | 21.03.2024 15:24 | 21.03.2024 15:24 | 21.03.2024 | 15:24:38 | 192 | +03:00 | INF | Messaeg-i - 1 |
| 2024-03-21 15:24:39,490 +03:00 | 2024-03-21 15:24:39,490 | 21.03.2024 15:24 | 21.03.2024 15:24 | 21.03.2024 | 15:24:39 | 490 | +03:00 | INF | Messaeg-i - 2 |
| 2024-03-21 15:24:40,821 +03:00 | 2024-03-21 15:24:40,821 | 21.03.2024 15:24 | 21.03.2024 15:24 | 21.03.2024 | 15:24:40 | 821 | +03:00 | INF | Messaeg-i - 3 |
| 2024-03-21 15:24:40,949 +03:00 | 2024-03-21 15:24:40,949 | 21.03.2024 15:24 | 21.03.2024 15:24 | 21.03.2024 | 15:24:40 | 949 | +03:00 | INF | Messaeg-i - 4 |

**PowerQuery**
[image]

**Excel**
[image]

**Code**

```
let
    Источник = Csv.Document(File.Contents("E:\Projects\39\01_pr\01\2024-03-21_15-24-36.csv"),
                    [Delimiter="|", 
                    Columns=10, 
                    Encoding=1251]),
    #"Измененный тип" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Источник,
                    {
                        {"Column1", type text}, 
                        {"Column2", type text}, 
                        {"Column3", type datetime}, 
                        {"Column4", type datetime}, 
                        {"Column5", type date}, 
                        {"Column6", type time}, 
                        {"Column7", Int64.Type}, 
                        {"Column8", type text}, 
                        {"Column9", type text}, 
                        {"Column10", type text}
                    }
                    )
in
    #"Измененный тип"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to use this in Excel, Excel does not have a `DateTimeZone` type, so I would eliminate that.

But you can convert your DateTime string into a "real" DateTime by transforming the column into a valid textual DateTime string first.

Here is representative code:

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\Times.txt"),[Delimiter="  ", Columns=10, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),

//We will only process column 2
    DateTime = Table.SelectColumns(Source,"Column2"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(DateTime, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),

//Create valid DateTime string by inserting a `T` before the Time component
    #"DateTime Type" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Promoted Headers", {
        {"Column2", each DateTime.FromText(Text.ReplaceRange(_,10,1,"T"),[Culture="en-150"]), type datetime}
    })
in
    #"DateTime Type"
```

In Power Query the dates are shown as in your local culture (mine is `en-US` or `m/d/y h:mm:ss AM/PM` but when you load it back to Excel, the milliseconds will be preserved and you can format however you wish.

[image]

And here is that same data, loaded to Excel and formatted to include seconds:

[image]

Comment: What code was used for formatting in Excel?
In other words: `ctrl + 1`. And then what did you enter?
To `2024-03-21 15: 24: 36.897` - milliseconds are separated by "`.`";

Comment: @eusataf `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000`. The dot `.` is my decimal separator. You will need to replace it with your decimal separator.